# Error when selecting more than one time a row of a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a sample form where I am testing `p:tabView` `p:tab` `p:datatable` where I can set the number of rows I want to show and select a row to show its content in other section of the form. The problem is that when I select a row of the table the content is only showed once. I can select different rows and the content is shown but if I select the same row more that one time I get this error:

```
WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-36] com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute /index.xhtml @43,153 listener="#{controlador.seleccionoFila}": java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @43,153 listener="#{controlador.seleccionoFila}": java.lang.NullPointerException
//more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Controller.Controlador.seleccionoFila(Controlador.java:81)
//more
13-Feb-2015 07:54:23.933 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-36] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I dont understand why. **I just know that if I remove the line that says Error in the ManagedBean - seleccionoFila() method it works. I dont know if it is because I am setting a value there, that is the only difference**

**Form**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:tabView id="tabView">
        <p:tab title="Uno">
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Introduce el valor de j:"/>
                        <p:inputText value="#{controlador.j}"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Listar tabla" action="#{controlador.listar}" update="tabla" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:dataTable id="tabla" value="#{controlador.listaDos}" var="d" rowKey="#{d.idUno}" selectionMode="single" selection="#{controlador.dosSeleccionado}">
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{controlador.seleccionoFila}" update=":form:tabView:pnlSeleccionado" />
                        <p:column headerText="ID">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{d.idUno}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Nombre">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{d.nombreUno}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Descripción">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{d.descripcion}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:panelGrid id="pnlSeleccionado" columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="ID seleccionado"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{controlador.dosSeleccionado.idUno}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Nombre seleccionado"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{controlador.dosSeleccionado.nombreUno}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Descripcion seleccionado"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{controlador.dosSeleccionado.descripcion}"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="Otro campo"/>
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{controlador.otro}"/>
                </p:panelGrid>

            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Controlador implements Serializable {

public Controlador() {
    this.dos = new Dos();
    this.j = 0;
    this.listaDos = new ArrayList<>();
    this.dosSeleccionado = new Dos();
}

private Dos dos;
private int j;
private List<Dos> listaDos;
private Dos dosSeleccionado;
private int otro;

//setters and getters

public void listar() {
    this.listaDos = this.dos.listarDos(this.j);
}

public void seleccionoFila() {
    this.otro = this.dosSeleccionado.getIdUno() * this.dosSeleccionado.getIdUno();
    /*Error*/this.dosSeleccionado.setIdUno(this.dosSeleccionado.getIdUno() + 10);
}

}
```

**Uno**

```
public class Uno implements Serializable{

private int idUno;
private String nombreUno;

//setters and getters

public LinkedList listarUno() {
    LinkedList<Uno> listaUno = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 10; i < 21; i++) {
        Uno u = new Uno();
        u.idUno = i;
        u.nombreUno = i + " " + (i + i);
        listaUno.add(u);
    }
    return listaUno;
  }
}
```

**Dos**

```
public class Dos extends Uno implements Serializable {

private String descripcion;

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public LinkedList listarDos(int j) {
    LinkedList<Dos> lista = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        Dos d = new Dos();
        d.setIdUno(i);
        d.setNombreUno(i + " " + i);
        d.setDescripcion(i + " " + i + " " + i + " " + i);
        lista.add(d);
    }
    return lista;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Selecting "twice" the same items means that you deselect it. Thus `dosSeleccionado` is null and you get a NPE.

Comment: @SJuan76 at the beginning of the method `seleccionoFila` I checked that if the value is null : then instanciate it, this means that it is not getting the selected value (when I click twice and to debug it and check what you said). So if i click it again should give me the value, no? I tried that but still null (the thrid time) so I dont think that is the problem. As I said when I remove the line that says **Error** in the method `seleccionoFila` it get the value (again and again) when I click the row. I dont understand why that.

Comment: My wrong, if the issue was `dosSeleccionado` you would have get a NPE in the previous line. The issue seems to be withing you `setIdUno` method.